# Change the Opacity of a View with a Swift Material without Altering The Visual Effect

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am trying to animate the transition of a (image) view in SwiftUI which is blurred using a system material visual effect:

```
ZStack {
   Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "Landscape-Color.jpg")!)
      .resizable()
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
      .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
   VisualEffectView(UIBlurEffect(style: .systemThinMaterial))
   Text("Hello, world!")
}.opacity(0.5)
```

You can find a playground with a complete code example [here](https://github.com/j0h4nn3s/SwiftMaterialTest).

The transition should animate the opacity of the view, without changing the blur effect of the swift material.
As you can see with the code example and the in the picture below, setting an opacity lessens the blur effect and makes the underlying content more visible. In my example, the visual effect should not change when the view is removed.

[image: Same ZStack with Visual effect view, the first one as a .opacity(0.5)]

I am looking for a solution how to lower the opacity of the ZStack without changing the look of the visual effect. (only the blue background behind should be more visible, not the picture within the view).

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I don't mind if the solution is in SwiftUI or UIKit, as long as I can embed everything somewhere in SwiftUI.
Please let me know, if anything is unclear.

Comment: Could you give an example of what it should look like when the opacity is 0 vs 1?
I wonder if moving the .opacity modifier to the image itself rather than the zstack works better for you?

Comment: @Chris moving the modifier to the image would indeed work in this example. But I want to transition a complex view, where only the background consists of an Image with a visual effect applied like in the example. The view contains many more elements like text, controls etc. The opacity effect should be applied to the whole view

Comment: I think it may be worthwhile posting a more detailed code setup, I have a feeling though it may end up being moving the VisualEffectView to a different view

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting he picture in the `.background`?

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct OpacityView: View {
    @State var opacity: CGFloat = 0.5
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Slider(value: $opacity)
            ZStack {
                Color.blue
                //Other View elements here
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }.opacity(opacity)
            
        }.background(
            Image(systemName: "person")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .overlay(Material.ultraThin)
        )
        
    }
}
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct OpacityView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OpacityView()
    }
}
```

It seems to provide the effect you want.

opacity == 0

[image]

opacity == 0.5

[image]

opacity == 1

[image]

At 1 the image is hidden by the `Color` since it is behind the `ZStack`. If this isn't what you want can you